# Publishing parameter updates to camera using pointgrey_camera_driver

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04 I would like to control the parameters of a BlackFly GiGE camera using pointgrey_image_driver.  I can see the image using image_view while running the driver.

It looks like the parameters should be accessible using dynamic reconfigure but when I publish messages from the command line, there is no effect on the image.  Examples of messages I have tried:

```
rostopic pub -1 /camera/camera_nodelet/parameter_updates dynamic_reconfigure/BoolParameter '{name: auto_white_balance, value: False}'

rostopic pub -1 /camera/camera_nodelet/parameter_updates dynamic_reconfigure/BoolParameter '{name: white_balance_red, value: 3}'
```

Actually, I'd just like to set all the parameters once so if there's a way to do that other than by using dynamic_reconfigure, that would be great to know.

When I look at the parameter_updates topic, I see that there are no subscribers to that topic.  That seems like a problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234619/publishing-parameter-updates-to-camera-using-pointgrey_camera_driver/) by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [synapsido](https://answers.ros.org/users/20161/synapsido/) on 2016-05-18**:
It's the unique camera that you have tried?
I have no problems using Flea3 1394b...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of poking at the topics directly, dynamic_reconfigure has a command-line client and a python API that probably provide what you're looking for. Both are documented on the [dynamic_reconfigure wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).

As a side note, I think that topic is used for the node to send updates when its parameters change; not for outside clients to change parameters.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1